# por qué no corre npm start?

Tags: nodejs, linux, web, npm

[image: error npm start]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al correr el comando "npm start" no muestra errores pero no corre la aplicacion sólo se queda en colgado como en la imagen . Ayuda por favor.

Comment: Intenta darle tiempo, ese comando hace operaciones que tardan **cierto tiempo.**

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por favor agrega el contenido de tu archivo `package.json`. El código debes agregarlo como texto y no como imagen. Saludos